# Spring jpa while creating hibernate session hits for tenant resolver

Tags: spring, hibernate, session, spring-data-jpa, multi-tenant

I have Multitenancy architecture setup in my project where I am using Spring JPA to manage hibernate session. While server is getting up, I see that everytime it is hitting CurrentTenantIdentifierResolver to resolve current tenant.

It is trying to create session builder every time. I need to understand is it because of JPA bean initialization or any other functionality that is causing it to hit tenant resolver multiple times.

As per my understanding, tenant resolver should be hit whenever we are making a DB call once server is up.

Please drop me any lead.

Comment: What hibernate version do you use?

Comment: hibernate version is 5.3.8.Final